# How to run a code for multiple fastq files?

Tags: python, biopython

I would run the following code for multiple fastq files in a folder. In a folder I have different fastq files; first I have to read one file and perform the required operations, then store results in a separate file. fastq and then read second file, perform the same operations and save results in new 2nd file.fastq. Repeat the same procedure for all the files in the folder.

How can I do? Can someone suggest me a way to this this?

```
from Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO import FastqGeneralIterator
fout=open("prova_FiltraN_CE_filt.fastq","w")
fin=open("prova_FiltraN_CE.fastq","rU")
maxN=0
countall=0
countincl=0
with open("prova_FiltraN_CE.fastq", "rU") as handle:
    for (title, sequence, quality) in FastqGeneralIterator(handle):
        countN = sequence.count("N", 0, len(sequence))
        countall+=1
        if countN==maxN:
            fout.write("@%s\n%s\n+\n%s\n" % (title, sequence, quality))
            countincl+=1
fin.close
fout.close
print countall, countincl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will do what you want. What I did was make your code into a function (and modified it to be what I think is more correct) and then called that function for every `.fastq` file found in the designated folder. The output file names are generated from the input files found.

```
from Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO import FastqGeneralIterator
import glob
import os

def process(in_filepath, out_filepath):
    maxN = 0
    countall = 0
    countincl = 0
    with open(in_filepath, "rU") as fin:
        with open(out_filepath, "w") as fout:
            for (title, sequence, quality) in FastqGeneralIterator(fin):
                countN = sequence.count("N", 0, len(sequence))
                countall += 1
                if countN == maxN:
                    fout.write("@%s\n%s\n+\n%s\n" % (title, sequence, quality))
                    countincl += 1
    print os.path.split(in_filepath)[1], countall, countincl

folder = "/path/to/folder"  # folder to process
for in_filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "*.fastq")):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(in_filepath)
    if not root.endswith("_filt"):  # avoid processing existing output files
        out_filepath = root + "_filt" + ext
        process(in_filepath, out_filepath)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!I tried and it is working right now!

Comment: @ChiaraE: You're welcome. I made a couple of small changes. The function now prints the name of the file it processed as well as the two counts when it's finished, plus the `for` loop at the end that controls file processing will avoid processing any existing output files. That way you if add files to the folder and the code will only process the new ones that don't have a corresponding output file.

Comment: Many thanks is really perfect; I can control thereby also the file that is processing! Thank you so much!!!